# UIScrollView with child UIView with a button on it not getting clicks

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a Hierarchy like this: UIScrollView -> UIView -> UIButton

I would like to click the UIButton but it appears the ScrollView is eating up all the events. How can an event be passed down to the UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. What solves the problem is to remove the UIView layer. Build you hierarchy like that UIScrollView -> UIButton.
I put the code from UIView in a subclass of UIButton.

Answer (score -1):

in the same case - when i scroll 1 page down, buttons are not response. buttons above, witch i see after viewDidLoad() are works fine.
try to set userInteractionEnabled = YES for your UIView